# How to frontend two wordpress sites running through two docker containers using nginx.

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker

I've two wordpress instances each running as one docker container. I would like to frontend / proxy these two wordpress instances through a single nginx server.

Following is my nginx config file.

```
upstream docker-site1 {
 server site1_site;
}

upstream docker-site2 {
 server site2_site;
}

server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    myserver.domain.com;

  proxy_set_header Host "myserver.domain.com"; # required for Docker client sake
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; #pass on real client IP
  client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
  # required to avoid HTTP 411: see issue #1486 (https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1486)
  chunked_transfer_encoding on;

  location /site2 {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass/.site1_htpasswd;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_pass http://docker-site2/;

  }

  location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass/.site1_htpasswd;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    add_header HTTP_HOST $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://docker-site1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this configuration causing a problem? What is the error?

Comment: this isn't a docker question. just nginx config...

Comment: im unable to access site2 when using myserver.domain.com/site2

Comment: Sure, this is not a docker problem. But the wordpress container itself is not able to understand being inside a sub-directory. Site2 wordpress container is not respecting the `/site2` and always sending the URLs as `myserver.domain.com/` instead of `myserver.domain.com/site2/`. Hence always going to the site-1 wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nginx-proxy image that proxifies automatically your containers. You can find it [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/). Run the proxy like this:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Then, you have to run your wordpress images with an environment variable

```
$docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com ...
$docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=bar.foo.com ...
```

Or, better, add an ENV directive in your Dockerfile and expose the port

```
# My Wordpress 1 Dockerfile
ENV VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But My problem is, I don't have multiple domains to point to different sites, if I've it, I could as well use multiple conf.d configuration files and do the same thing as the nginx-proxy is doing

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same using reverse proxy with ssl though. First you redirect everything to an https and then:

```
server {
    listen *:443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/certbundle.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    ssl_dhparam             /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;

    server_name myserver.domain.com;

    location /site1/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8030/; #your wordpress container should have the same port

            proxy_set_header Host    $http_host;

            proxy_read_timeout       3500;
            proxy_connect_timeout    3250;

            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;


            proxy_set_header   SSL_PROTOCOL       $ssl_protocol;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_CERT    $ssl_client_cert;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY  $ssl_client_verify;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_SERVER_S_DN    $ssl_client_s_dn;

            auth_basic "Area 51 - No trespassing beyound this point without authentication";
            auth_basic_user_file sec/htpasswd;
    }

    location /site2/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; # again, change the port

            proxy_set_header Host    $http_host;

            proxy_read_timeout       3500;
            proxy_connect_timeout    3250;

            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;


            proxy_set_header   SSL_PROTOCOL       $ssl_protocol;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_CERT    $ssl_client_cert;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY  $ssl_client_verify;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_SERVER_S_DN    $ssl_client_s_dn;

            auth_basic "Area 51 - No trespassing beyound this point without authentication";
            auth_basic_user_file sec/htpasswd;
    }
```

In the wp-config.php of your first site you should add this lines:

```
 define('WP_HOME', 'https://myserver.domain.com;/site1'); 
 define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://myserver.domain.com;/site1');
```

Make sure you are connected to your database. I guess you are using another container for your database? If yes configure these properties accordingly in your wp-config.php

```
define('DB_NAME', 'youDbName'); #default is wordpress
define('DB_USER', 'root');     
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'yourPass');    
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql'); # your db container name    
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

It should be more or less the same without ssl

EDIT:
and as ShanShan pointed out, make sure you run you container with -p option and the port you want i.e. for site 1 `-p 8030:80`